# Two radio buttons getting selected in Radio Group

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

[image]

Two buttons getting selected in the radio group.
I do not know where I am getting wrong. Please help me out.

```
final RadioGroup rg=new RadioGroup(Survay_MainActivity.this);
rg.clearCheck();
rg.setId(Integer.valueOf(entry1.getKey()));  
Log.v("rg getid", "rg"+rg.getId());
for(int i =0;i<values.size();i++){
    // Create Button
    final RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(Survay_MainActivity.this);
    btn.setId(i);
    btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    btn.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    btn.setText(values.get(i));

    rg.addView(btn);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSONObject quesAns = new JSONObject();
            String ans=btn.getText().toString().trim();
            try {
                quesAns.put(String.valueOf(rg.getId()), ans);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonarray.put(quesAns);    
            Log.v("jsonarray", "jsonarray"+jsonarray);
        }
    });
}     
views.addView(rg);
```

1) I am creating the RadioGroup out of the loop.

2) Adding radio button to the RadioGroup in the for loop

3) When the loop finishes the RadioGroup is added to the linerlayout.

Comment: You are creating a new Button each time through the loop - and because you have declared it as final you can access it inside the onClick handler - however this is bad because you are recreating the button each time - btn refers to the last button created not the one created when you went through the loop.

Comment: What is the value of entry1.getKey()?

Comment: As simo mentioned, you are creating a final button, and accessing it in the wrong way. `final` is actually useful, but not in such case - you get same button passed to `onClick` method, so better use that one. Next, you should use `onCheckChangeListener` on RadioGroup, instead of `onclick` on RadioButton. I do not know why there are two checked buttons, but try fixing these two problems first. Oh, and both groups seem to have same Id.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to change different ids for different radio button.
     There may be some id clash in gen file.
     **Radio button1 : android:id="@+id/one
     Radio button2 : android:id="@+id/two"
     Radio button3 : android:id="@+id/three"**

Hope this would help.

Comment: This issue occurs in random devices. once I gave ids to RadioButtons, It worked

Answer (score 2):

There are some things misplaced these changes you have to make out.

1.Change your `OnClickListener` by `OnCheckChangeListener`

2.Clear check your `radioGroup` after adding all `radioButtons` and before adding it in `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are setting an id for your items manually

```
rg.setId(Integer.valueOf(entry1.getKey()));  
btn.setId(i);
```

Android works with id's generated automatically that are different. Setting the id's manually it might happen that you give the same ID to the radio group and the radio button.
I used your code and set the group to ID 3 and radios from 0 to 4.
Needless to say that after I click the button with id 3 it always stays on because the group has the same id.
So, try to remove the id setting part, or, if you insist make sure you always have distinct id's.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The cause is the RadioGroup's id is same as one of RadioButtons

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line. you didn't send where is this code belonged to. when you get out of this scope and come back you will create new `RadioGroup`. You should have one and only one RadioGroup so the `RadioButton`s have same RadioGroup and by default one of them will be selected. To this, you can define RadioGroup in an XML and use this to define variable for it `RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.YOURNAME);` or you can define your RadioGroup as Instance  variable(Global).

```
final RadioGroup rg=new RadioGroup(Survay_MainActivity.this);
```